# Finding the differences between integers in the list

Tags: python, numpy

After much tinkering, I have finally come up with a piece of code that takes the differences between each of the integers in the *same* list, and dumps them into a new list.  Here's my code:

```
ints = [3, 5, 9, 15, 36]
difs = []
h = 0

while h < len(ints) - 1:    
    difs.append(ints[1 + h] - ints[0 + h])
    h = h + 1
print difs
```

When run, the list 'difs' contains [2, 4, 6, 21] (i.e. the differences between the integers in the 'int' list.

My question: is there any even simpler function--perhaps in numpy--that does this automatically?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function in `numpy`: [numpy.diff()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.diff([3, 5, 9, 15, 36])
array([ 2,  4,  6, 21])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> ints = [3, 5, 9, 15, 36]
>>> [b-a for a, b in  zip(ints, ints[1:])]
[2, 4, 6, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a function diff() in numpy. 
It can be used like this...

```
ints = [3, 5, 9, 15, 36]
x = numpy.array(ints)

numpy.diff(x)
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 21]
```

You can also use the same function to get the difference between two lists using axis parameter in the function.